# Display iAd banner with Local/Push notification

Tags: objective-c

I have to show iAd banner with local notification and push notification of my iPhone App. Is it possible in iOS? If it is possible, please suggest me its code in objective c.

Comment: Can you please describe what exactly you want and what have yo tried.

Comment: please elaborate clearly what exactly you want?

Comment: Whenever my app shows notification ,I want to show advertisement along with notification . It is possible in android. but I have no idea about iOS.

Comment: iAd is a thing of the past.